# unable to pass number into Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragment

`fragment` run:

```
            val fragment = DescriptionFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("position", position)
            fragment.setArguments(bundle)

            val activity=context.context as AppCompatActivity
            activity.supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment)
                .commitNow()
```

teaching a number inside a `fragment`:

```
val position: Int = getArguments()?.getInt("position", 0) ?: 0
```

but it is not possible to pass a number, `position` is always 0

in details:

```
class DescriptionFragment : Fragment() {

...

    val position: Int = getArguments()?.getInt("position", 0) ?: 0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

...
    }
```

Comment: In what lifecycle method are you trying to get position inside your fragment

Comment: @VojinPurić, outside of all methods

Comment: @VojinPurić, thanks, i ran the receive inside onCreateView and it worked

Comment: Yes that is what I suspected the issue was